# What makes apple(smartphone) so special?

Tags: iphone

Well, i never used an apple phone in my life, i am really curious why people are  really crazy for apple phones arent they just like the androids?what's so special?

Comment: For me, the two biggest things are SECURITY: Malware almost exclusively targets Android. I don't like to have to worry about viruses on my phone, and with the iPhone, I really don't. LONGEVITY: For the most part, Android phones run the version of Android they shipped with...and then that's it. iPhones seem to get updates for forever, like the iPhone 4 (from 2011) can still run the most current version of iOS 9.3.2, even though it shipped with iOS 5.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to try an iPhone, or read about it, to form your opinion about what is special about it (if you find anything special about it). You'll find that there's about as many different opinions about phones as there are people.

To use an analogy, which you should never do, you could ask what is so special about an Audi when it is just a car like a Toyota is a car?

For some there's no difference between the two. For others, the difference is monumental.